# Methods of reducing number of CSS calculations on webpage

Tags: css, performance, extjs

Our application at work uses the ExtJS (Sencha) framework for the UI. The problem I have with the framework is the amount of HTML that is output by the framework.

I have noticed that the areas of the system that are reported as being slow by users have a ton of CSS calculation calls. I measured this in Google's Speedtracer and some pages take 8seconds to load. 80% of the time is dedicated purely to CSS calculations. Before trying to alter the way the framework works, is there anyway to delay CSS calculation of a page, or are these calculations done when the objects are rendered?

I have been searching for ways to do this, and maybe my "google-fu" is terrible, but I haven't found anything concrete on how to achieve something like this.

EDIT: After speaking a colleague, he pointed me in the direction of calling .suspendEvents() on the grid before loading any data and .resumeEvents() afterwards, this alone has saved 300ms of loading time :O This is reducing the number .getStyle calls detected by Firebug. I am yet to test this difference with Google SpeedTracer

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. But usually CSS doesn't hold the page rendering. You mentioned the problem is the amount of output HTML and CSS calculation by ExtJS. I guess the problem is still caused by the JS rendering. Maybe you can try Firebug or Fiddler to trace requests to find bottleneck

Comment: Agreed.  There's no amount of CSS in the world that takes 8 secs to calculate unless it's running on a Telex or something.  I'd be curious to know more about how you're testing this.

Comment: if I could upload the SpeedTracer results I would, maybe I must try take a screenshot of it. SpeedTracer is different to firebug in that it actually shows when the UI is usable and when it isn't. Firebug and Fiddler show the time it takes to download the response from the server.

Comment: The last time I looked ExtJS rendering did a lot of absolute positioning. Possibly `autoHeight` or a different layout might help here, but it's something I haven't found a good answer to yet.

Comment: What sort of CSS calculations are there?  I've never really heard this term.  Do you mean Js calculations?  You can make lots of optimisations there to do with scope and things like that when manipulating the DOM

Comment: @Tom: The CSS Calculation is a measure of how long the browser takes to "decide" which styles should be applied to a DOM object. In the case of the ExtJs Framework, it outputs a lot of tables and sadly uses tables for layout. As RobertC points out in the answers below it may well be related to excessive reflows (http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say what's causing your performance problem without knowing exactly what your app is doing.  CSS will have some impact [but not much](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/), it's more likely that some JavaScript in your app is [causing excessive reflows](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) while the page is rendering.

**Summary of stubornella's article (the second link)**

Reflow is the process by which elements in a web page get laid out according to the style rules.  A reflow is computationally expensive but it is usually possible to draw a static HTML page in a single reflow as long as the rendering of any later elements doesn't effect elements that have already been drawn.  Things which are likely to lead to multiple reflows and some work arounds:

1. Dynamically adding CSS classes to elements - change classes as low in the dom tree as possible to limit the impact
2. Adding multiple DOM elements - create an invisible structure and add it in a single operation instead
3. Adding multiple inline styles to visible elements - better to create a class with all the styles, then apply the class
4. Applying animations to relatively positioned elements - better to animate `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` elements as they won't impact anything else
5. Fine grained animations - moving an element 3px at a time may be more smooth than moving it 1px at a time because you avoid two reflows
6. Tables are one of the few cases where the rendering of an element later in the DOM can change how an earlier element should be rendered - if you must use tables, use `table-layout: fixed`

Comment: Reading the article on reflows now and this looks promising, thanks.

EDIT: I am pretty sure this is exactly what is happening. The best piece of advice I see in the article is to avoid using tables for layout, sadly the Javascript framework in use does exactly that.

Comment: Robert: Could you please edit you answer to expand on reflows so that users don't need to follow the link and I will accept it as the answer. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

We have also been struggling with the overhead of using extJS - although the framework is very comprehensive, the performance hit (especially with IE6) has been a big limitation.  Here are some of the steps we took to optimize the framework:

1. **Streamline** the library to only include the packages that are used on your site.  This means customizing the jsb2 file and rolling your own extJS deployment.
2. In our performance testing we've identified the CSS to be the biggest offender.  A benefit of using a custom build of extJS is the **reduction of unused** CSS selectors.  To further optimize the CSS, we used **Google's Page Speed to identify the CSS selectors that are inefficient** to refactor/remove them. Pay particular attention to:

   - Pseudo **:hover** selector
   - Universal * key with descendant selectors

The resulting ext "lite" should yield significant performance gains, particularly in IE6.  Although the Secha team are making continuous performance improvements with every release, the overhead of loading the entire framework is too expensive to ignore.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Smartoptimizer is really awesome, have you tried any of those types of gzip code compression  type tools?

https://github.com/farhadi/SmartOptimizer

Comment: it's not about size, it's about number of DOM objects and number of css rules. Compression is usually associated with SLOWER processing.

Comment: As Alexander says, in this case it is already compressed, the issue at hand is the number of DOM objects and the time it takes the browser to calculate the rules assigned to each dom object and render it